# Google calendar event publish link is working in PC and not working in mobile properly

Tags: google-calendar-api

I created an public event in my google public calendar with location time and details.

**Creating an event in my public calendar.**
[image: Creating an event in my public calendar.]

**Going to the particular event and click on public event**
[image: Going to the particular event and click on public event]

**Coping the event link**
[image: Coping the event link]

**EVENT LINK**

https://calendar.google.com/event?action=TEMPLATE&tmeid=M3ZqdTVlc2I0b2tmcDZhaDJjdm1uZHVvM2ggbXlwaWNzMzI1NjdAbQ&tmsrc=mypics32567%40gmail.com

This link is working fine in PC and not working in Mobile(app).

Can anyone please help me how to make it working in mobile too. 
In mobile when we click on this link it will create a link with all details but time will be wrong (it will take current time as event time and create :D)

Comment: Same issue here. On iOS the Google calendar app says "event not found".